# Angular js filtering is needed at object property level instaed at object level for ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am trying to search a list with input text entry,

```
<input disable-auto-close  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" ng-model="query" stop-event />
</div>
</li>
<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="eachObj in objList | filter:query" >
   <a class="dd-li-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >
      {{eachObj.name}}      
   </a>
</li>
```

I realized that my filter is searching at object level, instead object name property level. I mean, if I type "a", it should search eachObj.name, instead eachObj. My current search is resulting if any property of eachObj contains "a" then it is showing that, instead only if eachObj.name contains "a" then only it should display that name. is there any simple fix for this.

The following are my sample json and dropdown :

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <div class="smp-list-selected btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="smp-list-selected-label">{{sampleCtrl.dropdownSelectedLabel}}</div>
      <div class="caret dropdown-caret"></div>
      <div class="subscript-indicator" ng-if="sampleCtrl.isQualified(sampleCtrl.selectedsmp.id)">Qualified</div>
   </div>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu smp-list" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" auto-close="outsideClick">
      <li role="presentation" >
         <div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control-for-smps"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
            <input disable-auto-close  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" ng-model="query" stop-event />
         </div>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="smpObj in sampleCtrl.smpList | filter:{name:query} " ng-click="sampleCtrl.selectsmp(smpObj)">
         <a class="dd-li-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >
            {{smpObj.name}}
            <div class="subscript-indicator" ng-if="sampleCtrl.isQualified(smpObj.id)">Qualified</div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>

 vm.smpList = [
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Check",   
    "status": "Sent"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Tupper",    
    "status": "In"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Dangi",    
    "status": "Out"
  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object notation of filter. So `| filter:{<propName>:<Value>}` to search properties of your items.

So in your case

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{name:by}">
```

Will filter where the `object.name` contains the scope property `by`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

See fiddle of it in action
http://jsfiddle.net/gfwex7jd/

Comment: Actually I have used ng-repeat  to repeat the dropdown options when I use your solution filter:{name:query}, none of the drop down options are visible. I have edited the question with sample json and dropdown.

Comment: The reason is by default ng-model="query" will be null/empty, so none of the down items are getting displayed,  only search input box is getting displayed under dropdown items.

Comment: The filter will still display all items even if you do not initialize the `ng-model` param. Remove it from the controller in my fiddle. It will then show all the results. I have coppied your html and data structure into my fiddle and it works correctly. that is however without your dropdown library. It may be helpfull to know what that is as it may be causing issues. http://jsfiddle.net/gfwex7jd/2/